# What is the effect of merging categories on logistic regression estimates?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, pooling

I have a logistic regression with a number of predictors variables including a factor with, say, 5 categories. The estimates for that factor compare categories 2-5 in turn to the reference category zero.
If I merge 2 of the non-reference categories (say merge 2 and 3) then the estimates for the other change slightly. I think this is because estimates will be correlated in a non-orthognal design but I'd like confirmation or a more thorough explanation please.

#### Edit

to be honest my colleague has such a problem with conditional logistic regression but the same issue occurs with ordinary logistic regression and I suspect in regressoin generally.
for myself I'd like to know for general knowledge what the issue is (as well as to reassure my colleague
I hope it is OK to post code (I hope it doesn't get too scrambled - I indented the code) but this illustrates the occurence with the generally available (e.g. in `R` package `MASS` from the Venables and Ripley book) dataset `birthwt` where binary outcome "low birthweight" is modelled by logistic regression - I have a factor `ftv` (which I make groups 0-4 by merging then I create s copy `fvt2` where groups 1 and 2 are merged to be "2".
The estimates in both analyses compare group zero to the other groups and you can see below the comparison of group 4 to 0 changes (slightly - I've put them in bold). Why? the data for those 2 groups in unaltered but I can see there is an issue of correlated estimates here.
Many thanks for any advice.

```
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
birthwt$ftv<-ifelse(birthwt$ftv>3,4,birthwt$ftv)
# change 4 or more to 4
birthwt$ftv2<-birthwt$ftv
# create duplicate
birthwt$ftv2<-ifelse(birthwt$ftv==1,2,birthwt$ftv)
# then merge categories in duplicate
table(birthwt$ftv,birthwt$ftv2) 
# 1 and 2 for ftv become 2 in ftv2


    0   2   3   4
0 100   0   0   0
1   0  47   0   0
2   0  30   0   0
3   0   0   7   0
4   0   0   0   5


low_log<-glm(low ~  ht + ui + lwt +as.factor(ftv), data= birthwt,family = binomial)
coef(summary(low_log))

               Estimate  Std. Error    z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      1.15892582 0.852443200  1.3595344 0.173977321
ht               1.87181914 0.710991788  2.6326874 0.008471227 
ui               0.90472684 0.442643299  2.0439185 0.040961597
lwt             -0.01627838 0.006638716 -2.4520372 0.014204999
as.factor(ftv)1 -0.55718506 0.419152552 -1.3293133 0.183744632
as.factor(ftv)2 -0.39179846 0.501082892 -0.7819035 0.434271296
as.factor(ftv)3  0.76139653 0.837278585  0.9093706 0.363154537
as.factor(ftv)4 **-0.17724595** 1.183684076 -0.1497409 0.880969020

low_log<-glm(low ~  ht + ui + lwt +as.factor(ftv2), data= birthwt,family = binomial)
coef(summary(low_log))

                Estimate  Std. Error    z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)       1.14052105 0.850496353  1.3410064 0.179918375
ht                1.84783639 0.704472332  2.6230078 0.008715729
ui                0.91241494 0.441875434  2.0648691 0.038935385
lwt              -0.01612754 0.006620628 -2.4359530 0.014852614
as.factor(ftv2)2 -0.49476082 0.354944684 -1.3939097 0.163344887
as.factor(ftv2)3  0.76274256 0.836785227  0.9115153 0.362023910
as.factor(ftv2)4 **-0.17931225** 1.183211033 -0.1515471 0.879544125
```

Actually if you remove the other variables - `ht`, `ui` and `lwt`, then the estimates/contrasts for groups 4 and 3 vs 0 are unaffected!
The estimates are always the difference in log odds between the 2 groups
I am uneasy this is well understood (at least by others).

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your data, or say a little bit more about what the data are, what your situation is, what you've found, and what your goals are?

Comment: I've just realised that if you remove the other variables, ht/ui/lwt, from the analyses then the estimate/contrast of group 4 (or group 3) vs group 0 IS unaffected by pooling groups 1 and 2. It is simply the difference in log odds between 0 and 4 in each case !
I am uneasy that this is probably something that is well understood (by others :) )